# CSS Content Does Not Align To Screen Size

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

so I have a landing jsx page which is currently made up for 2 components, a main page and an About page, these pages have been placed inside a container which uses flexbox to align them vertically. While the content int the About page works as it should (for now its just an svg), when i decrease the vertical screen size, it covers and hides the content that overflows from the main page, when i set overflow to hidden the content is just not visible, but then its not set to hidden the svg from the About page overlaps the content from the main page, when instead i wanted the main page content to resize itself to fit the viewport height of the mobile device. Any suggestions?

```
.main-slim{
    color:#F86666;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    width:100vw;height:100vh;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: center;
}
```

Here, the main slim className refers to the mobile view for the main page.

```
.about-mobile-container{
    height:100vh;
    .line-graphic-scroll{
        //position:fixed;
        top:0;
        left:0;
        width:100%;
        height:100%;
        text-align: center;
        //overflow: hidden;
    }
    svg{
        display: inline-block;
        height: 100%;
    }
}
```

And here is the full scss file for the About page, which overlaps the main page when the screen height gets small.

```
return(
<>
<div className='absolute-container'>
    <div className='main-slim'>
        //content in main slim
    </div>

    <div className='about-mobile-container'>
        //content in about container
    </div>
</div>
</>
)
```

And here is a representation (not the actual code) of the landing.jsx script that renders the two pages. They are contained in the 'absolute-container' and are in a flexbox set to column.

Comment: when you use `flex-direction:column;` it changes the main-axis. which switches the use of `align-items` & `justify-content` so they work opposite to what you see with  `flex-direction:row;`

Comment: Could you also provide the styling done for `absolute-container` ?

Comment: HI, There is no styling for absolute container.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, you could use @media query (https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_mediaqueries.asp) to have a different style for differently-sized devices.

Comment: HI, thanks a lot for the response. I actually have not thought about using media query for vertical resizing! If I can't find a cleaner fix ill do that.

Comment: @SudoCrypted, glad I could help you.